# Многопоточность или многонитевость?

Tags: многопоточность, потоки-данных, терминология

Недавно у меня возник любопытный вопрос лингвистического характера.
**Почему многонитевость называют многопоточностью?**

В программировании есть два различных понятия `stream` и `thread`.

Первое обозначает объект для выполнения операций (чаще всего передача данных или их накопление), второе же обозначает объект, который позволяет выполнить некий программный код параллельно с другими ветками кода.

Первое слово переводится на русский язык как `поток` - тут всё логично, их так все и называют. Второе же слово переводится как `нить`.

Так почему в различного рода литературе и других медиа источниках это слово упорно переводят, как *поток*? Более того, в русском языке прочно закрепился термин *многопоточность*, который является аналогом (но никак не переводом) слова *multithreading*? Чем же можно объяснить столь любопытное явление? Или всё таки есть разница между многопоточностью и многонитевостью? А если есть разница, то какой в английском языке существует аналог термину *многонитевость*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Поток = нить (если мы говорим про "потоки" (Thread), а не потоки (Stream)). А про подмену понятия, можно почитать в [Вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread#.D0.9A.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B0_.D1.82.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.BC.D0.B8.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.BB.D0.BE.D0.B3.D0.B8.D0.B8)

> Перевод английского термина thread как
> «поток» в контексте, связанном с
> программированием, противоречит его же
> переводу «нить» в общеязыковом
> контексте, а также создает коллизии с
> термином stream («поток»).
>
> Однако, термин «поток» связан с
> переводами иностранной технической
> литературы, выполненными в 1970-х
> годах издательством «Мир». В настоящее
> время в «академических кругах» (то
> есть в учебниках, методических
> пособиях, курсах вузов, диссертациях и
> пр.) он считается эталонным. Термины
> же «нить», «тред» и т. п. считаются
> техническими жаргонизмами.

Comment: Традиционно считается, что ответ в стиле "так сложилось исторически" не является удовлетворительным ответом на вопрос типа "почему?". Формально такой ответ вроде бы подходит. Но он слишком универсален и не затрагивает суть вопроса.

Comment: @Shamov: Ну а какой ответ можно ещё дать на вопрос о терминологии? Неужели кто-то сможет вскрыть _причину_ того, что термин «поток» победил термин «нить»? У нас ведь не форум лингвистов.

Comment: @VladD Её и вскрывать не надо. Она на поверхности. Термины заимствуются в язык не как получится. Другие слова - возможно, но термины - точно нет. Для них существует определённый алгоритм. И хотя он придуман лингвистами, программистов не должно удивлять существование такого алгоритма. Эта идея должна быть им близка.

Comment: @Shamov: Не думаю, что семантика настолько реально важна. Переняли же мы французскую игру слов «не в своей тарелке» без понимания семантики.

Comment: @VladD Во-первых, "не в своей тарелке" - это не термин. Во-вторых, алгоритм допускает калькирование в тех случаях, когда более близкого по смыслу слова в языке нет. И, в-третьих, что в терминологии может быть важнее семантики? :)

Comment: @Shamov: Традиция? У нас же используют слово «компьютер» вместо семантичного «электронно-вычислительная машина»? :)

Comment: @VladD Слово "компьютер" предпочтительнее в силу простоты и краткости. Для терминологии это важно. Другой пример - "промоушен" вместо "продвижение товара на рынке". Но при всей важности краткости семантика намного важнее. Если бы у слова "промоушен" в русском языке уже существовало неудобное значение, то победил бы длинный вариант. Такие случаи были. Например, "работы по устройству пола" вместо "половые работы".

Comment: @Shamov: «ЭВМ» ещё короче. Однако...

Comment: @VladD ЭВМ - это аббревиатура. Там, где это уместно, она используется. Но разговаривать только аббревиатурами нельзя. В качестве отступления замечу, что когда человек использует в своей речи много аббревиатур - это считается одним из клинических признаков тяжелого расстройства психики.

Answer (score 4):

Термин *поток* означал раньше *process*, а *thread* - то есть *нить* понятие возникло относительно недавно, когда стало выделяться понятиe нити как части процесса.

Сейчас в общем понятие потока и нити синонимы, хотя надо понимать, что иногда под потоком может пониматься процесс. Но под нитью процесс никогда не понимается.

Различия между [процессом и нитью](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/66405/Processes_and_Threads)

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, а еще можно вспомнить неразбериху (сейчас это уже седая старина) с задачами (они же TASK). 

В одних местах это был синоним для process, а в других thread.

Кстати, понятие потоков (их-то и называли task), как нескольких независмых последовательностей команд в рамках одного процесса (или работающих с общей памятью) возникло давно (уже в 60-х).

Comment: @avp какой же ты старый :)

Comment: @Barmaley похоже, что старше PL/I (тип TASK -- оттуда). А это середина 60х

Answer (score 4):

Помимо тупого калькирования, при котором термин переходит в другой язык в форме буквального перевода (возможно, даже частичного), существует ещё семантическое заимствование, при котором термином в целевом языке становится слово, лучше всего подходящее по смыслу.

"Многонитевость" - это тупая калька с английского. Оригинальный термин просто переведён по частям. Более того, иногда можно встретить людей, которые используют в качестве термина частичную кальку - "многотредовость".

"Многопоточность" - это полноценное заимствование на уровне семантики. Для обеих частей термина подобраны русские слова, идеально соответствующее смыслу самого понятия, а не того слова, которым оно обозначается в чужом языке. Очевидно, что слово "поток" подходит по смыслу гораздо лучше, чем слово "нить". Это даже сами американцы понимают, потому что когда они говорят о потоке комманд, они используют термин "control flow".

Ну, а то, что русское слово "поток" соответствует сразу двум понятиям ("thread" и "stream"), вообще не проблема. Как правило, из контекста всегда можно понять, какое из этих двух понятий имеется в виду. А контекст - это всегда самое главное. От него смысл зависит в гораздо большей степени, чем от самого текста. Мой любимый пример, который это иллюстрирует: "Американцы слишком много жрут". Казалось бы, смысл фразы очевиден. А теперь представьте, что контекстом для неё является разговор двух автомобилистов, обсуждающих достоинства и недостатки различных автомобилей. В таком контексте смысл фразы был бы иным: "Автомобили американского производства потребляют слишком много топлива".

Comment: Семантическое заимствование происходило как на уровне «потока» (про те времена пишет @barmaley), так и позже на уровне «нити». В случае составных слов включился механизм калькирования, поэтому назвать только одно из них «тупой» калькой не будет верным. Раз у нас тут лингвистический уголок: прото-германский предок thread по форме и смыслу родственник нашим «прясти», «прядь», то есть процесс сплетается из нитей. Слово «flow», напротив, не имеет материальной смысловой составляющий, зато имеет временную/процессуальную. Поэтому, что там у вас американцы «сами понимают» — большой вопрос. ;)

Comment: @idlesign Во-первых, семантическое заимствование не могло произойти два раза. Результаты первого раза отменить не так просто, как это может показаться. Особенно в случае, когда первый раз был более удачным. Идея о том, что процессы сплетаются из нитей - это порождение чьей-то больной фантазии (надеюсь, не вашей). Нормальные люди так о процессах и потоках не думают. Скорее всего кто-то просто не разобрался в предмете, и его бурная фантазия породила этот чудовищный образ.

Comment: @idlesign Во-вторых, семантическое заимствование не может происходить через механизм калькирования. Это взаимоисключающие вещи. Как рука может быть либо правой, либо левой. Они обе нужны. Но каждая является какой-то одной. Или как помилование и казнь. Может быть что-то одно. Даже если говорить не абстрактно, а о конкретном механизме... например, о повешении. Нельзя сказать, что кто-то был помилован через повешение.

Comment: Вы, наверное, снова читаете между строк, я ничего не говорил ни про _сем. заимствование через калькирование_, ни про наоборот. Я говорил про стадии формирования составных слов. Помимо этого, никаких результатов отменять не требовалось: вариативность русского обуславливается полисемантичностью английского. Ну, и наконец, ваше изречение про больную фантазию и нормальность людей пространно: в большинстве ОС нити являются частью процесса, а переплетение (thread, twist) явствует уже из разделения ими одного адресного пространства, инструкций, контекста.

Comment: @idlesign Перечитайте себя. О том, что семантическое заимствование произошло через калькирование, написано не между строк.

Comment: @idlesign Вот у меня сейчас на столе стоит монитор, лежат клавиатура и мышь. Все они разделяют общее пространство стола. Можно даже назвать его адресным. Я запросто могу адресовать эти объекты некими координатами относительно какой-нибудь особой точки на столе. Более того, в динамике они даже связаны друг другом. Движение мыши приводит к движению стрелочки на мониторе. Внимание, вопрос! Значит ли это, что монитор, клавиатура и мышь переплетены?

Comment: Нити — волокна процесса, планировщик ОС — челнок. Не получается как-то у нас с вами продуктивной дискуссии: вы то видите в тексте то чего нет, то уходите в странные аналогии. Поэтому, сразу прошу простить, в последующем вступать в дискуссии для объяснения своей отрицательной оценки ответу не стану. Если вам всё же интересны мнения других людей, хоть и с больной фантазией, можете обратиться, например, к http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225371

Comment: @idlesign Уверяю вас, дискуссия не получается по вашей вине. И не нужно просить прощения за то, что в будущем избавите меня от необходимости в неё вступать. Наоборот, я буду благодарен, если вы сможете себя сдерживать. Ваша ссылка, кстати, полностью подтверждает мою версию. Во-первых, уже в самом вопросе сказано, что называть поток исполнения комманд словом "thread" - контринтуитивно. Во-вторых, в одном из ответов прямым текстом сказано, что это не более, чем метафора. Метафоры и идиомы почти никогда не заимствуются буквально.